# Javascript function is returned as undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to create a simple rock paper scissors game. However, when I click on the `submit` my `CalcWinner();` gets a console error "function is not defined".

I'm sure I'm missing something easy, any  suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Rock - Paper - Scissors</title>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <p>Click the button to pick rock, paper or scissors.</p>

<input type = "text" id = "picker" />
<button onclick="calcWinner();">Make your Selection?</button>

<!-- <input type = "submit" value="Make your Selection"/> -->
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="score"></p>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

var myChoice = "";
var compChoice = "";
var myScore = 0;
var compScore = 0;
    
  
    function calcWinner() { 
    myChoice = document.getElementById("picker");    
    compChoice = Math.random();
    if (compChoice < 0.33) {
        compChoice = "rock";
    } else if(compChoice < 0.67) {
        compChoice = "paper";
    } else {
        compChoice = "scissors";
    }
    
    if (compChoice == myChoice) {
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "It's a tie! You picked " + myChoice + " and the computer picked " + compChoice;
    } else if (compChoice == "rock") {
        if(myChoice == "scissors") {
         compScore ++; 
           document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You lose! You picked " + myChoice + " and the computer picked " + compChoice;
           
        } else if (myChoice == "paper") {
            userScore ++;
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You win! You picked " + myChoice + " and the computer picked " + compChoice;
        } else if (myChoice == "paper") {
        }
    } else if (compChoice == "paper") {
        if (myChoice == "rock") {
         compScore ++; 
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You lose! You picked " + myChoice + " and the computer picked " + compChoice;
        } else if (myChoice == "paper") {
        } else if (myChoice == "scissors") {
         userScore ++;
         document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You win! You picked " + myChoice + " and the computer picked " + compChoice;
        } else if (myChoice == "paper") {
        }
    } else if (compChoice == "scissors") {
        if (myChoice == "rock") {
         userScore ++;
           document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You win! You picked " + myChoice + " and the computer picked " + compChoice + " you have " + userScore;
        } else if (myChoice == "paper") {
        } else if (myChoice == "paper") {
         compScore ++; 
           document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You lose! You picked " + myChoice + " and the computer picked " + compChoice;
        } else if (myChoice == "paper") {
        }

    }
};
 






 });
</script>
```

Comment: Dont't wrap your `calcWinner` method in ready function.

Comment: Move `calcWinner` out of `ready`, it'll be _private_ and cannot be accessed from outside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `calcWinner` is created within a closure scope, so it is not accessible from the global scope.

Since you are using jQuery instead of using inline event handlers use jQuery to register the click handler within the dom ready handler like below

Also you need to read the value of the input field so `myChoice = document.getElementById("picker").value;` or `myChoice = $("#picker").val()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var myChoice = "";
  var compChoice = "";
  var myScore = 0;
  var compScore = 0;


  $('#selection').click(calcWinner);
  
  function calcWinner() {
    myChoice = document.getElementById("picker").value;
    compChoice = Math.random();
    if (compChoice < 0.33) {
      compChoice = "rock";
    } else if (compChoice < 0.67) {
      compChoice = "paper";
    } else {
      compChoice = "scissors";
    }

    $("#demo").html("");
    if (compChoice == myChoice) {
      $("#demo").html("It's a tie! You picked " + myChoice + " and the computer picked " + compChoice);
    } else if (compChoice == "rock") {
      if (myChoice == "scissors") {
        compScore++;
        $("#demo").html("You lose! You picked " + myChoice + " and the computer picked " + compChoice);

      } else if (myChoice == "paper") {
        userScore++;
        $("#demo").html( "You win! You picked " + myChoice + " and the computer picked " + compChoice);
      } else if (myChoice == "paper") {}
    } else if (compChoice == "paper") {
      if (myChoice == "rock") {
        compScore++;
        $("#demo").html("You lose! You picked " + myChoice + " and the computer picked " + compChoice);
      } else if (myChoice == "paper") {} else if (myChoice == "scissors") {
        userScore++;
        $("#demo").html("You win! You picked " + myChoice + " and the computer picked " + compChoice);
      } else if (myChoice == "paper") {}
    } else if (compChoice == "scissors") {
      if (myChoice == "rock") {
        userScore++;
        $("#demo").html("You win! You picked " + myChoice + " and the computer picked " + compChoice + " you have " + userScore);
      } else if (myChoice == "paper") {} else if (myChoice == "paper") {
        compScore++;
        $("#demo").html("You lose! You picked " + myChoice + " and the computer picked " + compChoice);
      } else if (myChoice == "paper") {}

    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Click the button to pick rock, paper or scissors.</p>

<input type="text" id="picker" />
<button id= "selection">Make your Selection?</button>

<!-- <input type = "submit" value="Make your Selection"/> -->
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="score"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should move calcWinner to global.Because it's private in ready function. Window cannot access it.

Answer (score 0):

Your cal winner function is inside the jQuery closure function. The window object cannot access it. You can either move it outside of ready function or use jQuery('button').on('click', calcwinner);